# "It's good until it's not" expression

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I came across the construction "X to be Y until it [not to be Y]" several times..For example in [Silicon Valley TV Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpG4bNCc7Pk):

> That was pretty badass Richard, until it wasn’t

and I always thought that it literally means "X to be Y until something happens". Recently I tried to use this construction in the article named "[ES6 is great, until it’s not](https://medium.com/@sAbakumoff/es6-is-great-until-its-not-f398339d0af6#.2mv678iju)"(ES6 is programming language) and the main point of the article is ES6 is OK to use as soon as it does not bring serious problems. However, I can see from the comments and replies that many perceive the content like I am trying to discredit ES6 which was not my intention at all..I suspect that it happened because the name does not actually means what I thought it means..So, I need help - what's the actual meaning of "X to be Y until it [not to be Y]" and whether it has fully negative connotations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a strongly negative connotation to 'until it's not'. It implies that a person will be blindsided by a (often sharp or drastic) turn for the worse or that they will become disillusioned by the reality of a thing. The part that comes before, in your case "is great", doesn't counter balance the 'until it's not', in fact it has a tone of sarcasm, it's commenting on how the 'great' doesn't mean much after it takes a turn for the worse.

Comment: OMG. Now I can see why people reacted to the article that specific way..I guess it's better avoid expressions that I don't understand fully..

Comment: Very nice. Upvote.